# Fetch mock method returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking, fetch-api

If I use the following code to test the fetch method of function user my await fetch always resolves to undefined. Any ideas why?

```
global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
  Promise.resolve({
    json: () => Promise.resolve({
        name: "test user"
    })
  })
);

const user = async () => {
    try {const url = `/users/user`;
        const response = await fetch(url) //resolves to undefined
        return await response.json()
    } catch(e) {
        return e;
    }
}

test('get mock user', async () => {
    const userName = await user();
    expect(userName).toEqual({ name: "test user"});
})
```

Comment: The code is ok. You won't be able to cause null with it. Debugging `e` on your side could help to understand what went wrong. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. In case of doubt try to replicate it in isolated environment like repl.it

Comment: @EstusFlask You are right, that was a good idea. I edited the question to be more precise because await fetch just resolves to undefined, which I don't understand

Comment: It still won't be able to reproduce it.  Your another question shares the same problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65092376/jest-fn-returns-undefined-when-called Your case differs from what you posted. The only way it's possible is that global.fetch was mocked before and was forced to be read-only. Btw mocking with `= jest.fn()` is a terrible practice.

Comment: I am not planning on doing it manually but "jest-fetch-mock" is not working for me, so I am trying to figure out what happens manually. But I don't understand what you mean, is the code above working for you? Because I created a brand new clean react app put solely the code above in my App.test.js file, and its not working because `await fetch(url, options)` returns `undefined`. If I leave out global.fetch = .... then it says 'network request failed' as it should. So the `global.fetch` IS changing that behaviour, but for some reason it's returning `undefined` and I have no idea why.

Comment: Yes, it works for me. The code is correct and has no chance to not work in this state. *then it says 'network request failed' as it should* - it shouldn't, there's no `fetch` in Node, that you have this error means that fetch was polyfilled, which isn't desirable in tests and most likely is the cause of the problem, this is specific to your React project. As I mentioned, a mock will fail if `fetch` is already read-only. To be clear, a correct way to mock an existing global would be `jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch')...` for several reasons. If it's read-only, it will output a meaningful error.

Comment: In case this is the problem, a solution will be something like `Object.defineProperty(global, 'fetch', { writable: true }); jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockImplementation(() => ...)`.

Comment: Actually the last 2 comments are not true. First of all, while true there is no fetch in node, there is a polyfill in the typical react setup the author describes. The problem is caused by `resetMocks` configuration as stated in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

i know the question is from a little while ago but i came here facing the same problem via search-engine, so i thought this might help:

Actually the problem is caused by Create-React-App has `resetMocks` set to true (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/68214648). So your mock is reset before the test runs. If you move it inside the `test()`-block, it should be fine.

So either configure mocks not to reset or mock it elsewhere. I hope this helps.