# jest.fn returns undefined when called

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, func

I am trying to implement a fetch mock function in my test. Following tutorials I am trying to do this by using `jest.fn()`:

```js
const fetchFunction = jest.fn(() => {
    return null
})
```

This does not work for some reason.
If I just do `console.log(fetchFunction)` in my test I get:

```js
[Function: mockConstructor] {
        _isMockFunction: true,
        getMockImplementation: [Function],
        mock: [Getter/Setter],
        mockClear: [Function],
        mockReset: [Function],
        mockRestore: [Function],
        mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
        mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function],
        mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function],
        mockReturnValue: [Function],
        mockResolvedValue: [Function],
        mockRejectedValue: [Function],
        mockImplementationOnce: [Function],
        mockImplementation: [Function],
        mockReturnThis: [Function],
        mockName: [Function],
        getMockName: [Function]
      }
```

However if I try to invoke it by `console.log(fetchFunction())` I get `undefined`?

I am trying this to do in a create-react-app folder. Do I have to install something extra? Any ideas about why this happens?

Answer (score 10):

It's because Create-React-App has `resetMocks` on by default. To turn it off you can put this in your package.json

```json
"jest": {
  "resetMocks": false
}
```

They changed this for the 4.0 release. And they did mention it in their changelog https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-2020-10-23 But I'm guessing I'm not alone in missing that/not knowing about that...

There is an open issue about reverting that change: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9935

Answer (score 2):

if your jest's `resetMocks` config attribute is set to `true`, you should expect that behavior according to the docs:

> Automatically reset mock state before every test. Equivalent to
> calling jest.resetAllMocks() before each test. This will lead to any
> mocks having their fake implementations removed but does not restore
> their initial implementation.

https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#resetmocks-boolean

With `resetMocks` set to `true`, I resolved it by defining my mock function implementation within the test itself:

```
it('your test' ()=> {
  //define your mock implementation here
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Validated that the following works as expected:

```
test('Some test...', () => {
  const fetchFunction = jest.fn(() => null)

  console.log(fetchFunction());
});
```

Using Jest 24.9.0.

```sh
 PASS  ./test.js
  ✓ foo (31ms)

  console.log test.js:6
    null

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.677s
Ran all test suites
```

Comment: Yes but if I define fetchFunction outside of test() it doesn't! I need to define my jest.fn function outside of test because I want to overwrite global.fetch with a mock function and that returns undefined as well, even though I saw it being done in many tutorials...

Comment: Not sure - I just moved the definition of the function to line 1 and it also worked fine. Here's the repl: https://repl.it/@xurion/scoped-jest-mocks